# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" VB.NET Issue

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am applying the following onclick event to a vb.net button in the server side code. I need the query string to contain the content of the products data attribute that I am assigning to btnGenerate.

I am getting the error in my Title when I click btnGenerate, I think it has something to do with my use of various quotation marks.

Changing the single apostrophes around #btnGenerate and products to double quotation marks results in the text: "$("#btnGenerate").data("products");" appearing in my query string instead of the values it should be retrieving.

```
Me.btnGenerate.Attributes.Add( _
    "onclick", _
    "return OpenPrinterFriendly('DespatchLabel.aspx?salesordernumber=" & _
    e.CommandArgument.ToString & " &newprocessdate=" & hdnNewProcessDate.Value & _
    "&products=$('#btnGenerate').data('products');')")
```

Comment: Try reformatting the code to multiple lines for readability on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your single quotes within the string with `\` character:

```
Me.btnGenerate.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
    "return OpenPrinterFriendly('DespatchLabel.aspx?salesordernumber=" & _
    e.CommandArgument.ToString & "&newprocessdate=" & hdnNewProcessDate.Value & _
    "&products=$(\'#btnGenerate\').data(\'products\');')")
```

---

**Edit:**

For retrieving the values using jQuery, you need to have this (similar to [Konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11291850/119230)'s response, although he's missing a `+` sign:

```
Me.btnGenerate.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
    "return OpenPrinterFriendly('DespatchLabel.aspx?salesordernumber=" & _
    e.CommandArgument.ToString & " &newprocessdate=" & hdnNewProcessDate.Value & _
    "&products=' + $('#btnGenerate').data('products'));")
```

Comment: That escaped the quotes nicely, though it is still only inserting the jquery as text into my querystring. Instead of retrieving the values. EDIT: I've just seen Konrad's answer and I'm going to give that a go. EDIT2: Kondrad's answer gives an unexpected identifier error.

Answer (score 0):

you have nested single quotes. Try this:

```
Me.btnGenerate.Attributes.Add( _
    "onclick", _
    "return OpenPrinterFriendly(""DespatchLabel.aspx?salesordernumber=" & _
    e.CommandArgument.ToString & " &newprocessdate=" & hdnNewProcessDate.Value & _
    "&products=$('#btnGenerate').data('products');"")")
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph I haven't done VB in years. Is `\"` not a valid escape sequence?

Comment: Its probably not a good idea trying to answer questions in languages you haven't used for years :-)

Comment: @Matt Depends, especially since VB and C# are so similar. I haven’t used VB (*or* C#, for that matter) in years and I’m in the top 5 users for VB.NET here on Stack Overflow. The top 1 (Jon Skeet) user has *never* used VB, as far as I know.

Comment: @MattWilko I figured fixing nested quoutes was safe :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the jQuery code to be executed, rather than being part of the query string. In that case, pull it out of the quotes:

```
Me.btnGenerate.Attributes.Add( _
    "onclick", _
    "return OpenPrinterFriendly('DespatchLabel.aspx?salesordernumber=" & _
    e.CommandArgument.ToString & " &newprocessdate=" & hdnNewProcessDate.Value & _
    "&products='$('#btnGenerate').data('products'));")
```

Otherwise, Miroslav’s answer is probably what you want.

Comment: Pull which bit out of the quotes, in my and Miroslav's code I can't see the JQuery part being enclosed in qotes?

Comment: @Korv No, in both your and Miroslav’s code the jQuery bit is inside the quotes.